# How do I call Objective-C class Categories in my library?

Tags: c#, xamarin, objective-c-category

I have an Objective-C library that I'm using in my Xamarin iOS project. I'm trying to create a UIImage class level category. The Objective Sharpie generated C# code looks like this:

```
// +(UIImage *)imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer;
[Static, Export ("imageFromSampleBuffer:")]
UIImage ImageFromSampleBuffer (CMSampleBuffer sampleBuffer);
```

However when I try to use it in my project, it isn't recognized as a class-level method. The following line generates an error about how UIImage does not contain a definition for ImageFromSampleBuffer.

```
var image = UIImage.ImageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer);
```

What do I need to alter to make this work?